# Can't connect to database in docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.13
    container_name: project-mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: project-webserver
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker/config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  php-fpm:
    build: ./docker/config/php
    container_name: project-php-fpm
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.17.0.1
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=docker
```

The problem is that php container can't connect to mysql.
Although from host I can connect with `mycli -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root`.
But when I exec in php container and try it, get 'Connection refused'

Comment: You need to use the `docker-compose.yml` service name as a host name, in this case `mysql`.  `localhost` in Docker always means "this container".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mysql service binds mysql server's port 3306 to 3306 of the host machine. Thus is it normal that you can connect from host.

From inside php container, `localhost` is referring to that particular container as @David Maze said in the comments.

Since you are using `docker-compose` containers are in the same network, so you should use the service name in order to connect to the mysql server.

Try this from php container:

`mycli -h mysql -P 3306 -u root`

Answer (score 1):

You are able to connect with user `root`. But in your docker-compose file, you are connecting through user `dbuser`. Let me know if that's not the issue.

Comment: No, this is not the issue, I can connect with dbuser as well.

Comment: @Mark i mean if you put root as user in your compose file. is that working? if not, try image: mysql:5.7

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't  change anything, root is created by default already and I set password for it.

Comment: @Mark root user may be able to connect from all source connections but dbuser might not have that privilege (assuming you have not given such permissions)

Comment: Yeah, sure. But it is created by default already and I even specified password for it  `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret`.  So I have this user in my setup, but it still don't work

Answer (score 0):

Usually conenction refused you get when request is coming from the different ip than it's bind-address. Try below should work.

- Make sure mysql configuration `my.cnf` or whatever default configs doesn't block connect from outside(check
  `bind-address` in the mysql configuration if it 127.0.0.1 the its only
  allow to connect form locally, i would for now make it 0.0.0.0 or
  commented that line if exists)

  - `mysqld --verbose --help` => you will see all options
  - `mysqld --verbose --help | grep bind-address` => check the bind-address
- Make sure the user i tried to login has enough privileges to
  connect(`SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;`) check your user can
  connect from docker network => `172.*` or anywhere=> `%`

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible due to cached volume.

Try deleting your volume:

```
$ docker volume prune

WARNING! This will remove all local volumes not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Volumes:
07c7bdf3e34ab76d921894c2b834f073721fccfbbcba792aa7648e3a7a664c2e
my-named-vol

Total reclaimed space: 36 B
```

And then try any one of these:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

OR

```
docker-compose up
```

***Remember:*** Before deleting your unused volumes run the following command if your docker-compose up is still running:

```
docker-compose down
```