# Java HttpURLConnection fails when communicating between Docker containers

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

The following code fails in conn.getResponseCode() with "Connection Failed"

```
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
```

The call is made between two Docker containers initialized with docker-compose.
Both containers are executing a Spring-Boot application.

The url uses the container name of the second container as the host name.

From within a bash shell in the first container, I can successfully do the following:

1. Ping the second container by container name
2. telnet to the second container by container name and port number
3. wget the json content using the url that is failing in the Java code

The error is as follows:

```
Exception in :- java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:540)
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:709)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1604)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
at com.formtek.transformer.executors.TestCodeExecutor.getGlobalDefaults(TestCodeExecutor.java:183)
at com.formtek.transformer.executors.TestCodeExecutor.createTransformCommand(TestCodeExecutor.java:107)
at org.alfresco.transformer.executors.TestCodeExecutor.<init>(AbstractExecutor.java:43)
at com.formtek.transformer.executors.TestCodeExecutor.<init>(TestCodeExecutor.java:39)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
at com.formtek.transformer.Application.main(Application.java:28)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
```

Comment: Could it be that the request is made before the target container is listening? There are generally only a couple of reasons for a connection refused, either the server is not listening or there is a firewall or other network device in-between refusing the connection. Your testing would seem to prove it's not the latter.

Comment: The target is available, so that's not it.  
I just found this reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649639/unable-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-on-localhost
I tried to add the other container under docker-compose links, but that didn't help.

Comment: 'Connection refused' means nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. And nothing else. You may think the target is available but the error message contradicts you.